# importing a picture from an openfiledialog into a picturebox, in visual c++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, openfiledialog

M stuck in importing a picture from an openfiledialog into a picturebox, in visual c++      windows form at Visual studio 2012... i searched it on different forums, and found one possible solution:-

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Select a picture";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
            "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
            "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            imgPhoto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
        }

    }
```

But in this solution or other solutions close to this one, does not allow me to create 
" new OpenFileDialog(); "

another solution, offered by microsoft for cursor file was...

```
private:
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object *  sender,
  System::EventArgs *  e)
{
  // Displays an OpenFileDialog so the user can select a Cursor.
  OpenFileDialog * openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
  openFileDialog1->Filter = "Cursor Files|*.cur";
  openFileDialog1->Title = "Select a Cursor File";

  // Show the Dialog.
  // If the user clicked OK in the dialog and
  // a .CUR file was selected, open it.
  if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == DialogResult::OK)
  {
     // Assign the cursor in the Stream to
     // the Form's Cursor property.
     this->Cursor = new
        System::Windows::Forms::Cursor(
        openFileDialog1->OpenFile());
  }
}
```

same problem in this too....

can any one suggest the easiest approach to do the required task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you are trying to use `C# sintax.` In `C++/CLI` you won't use `.` but the `->`, neither `new` or `*` for handles. You actually need `gcnew` and `^`.
Apart from this, look at this simple code:

**Note:** To be sure this example will compile, create a new project called `TestImage`, add a button called `btnLoad` and a picturebox called `pbImage`.

In `c++` it is better to separate your header file (`.h` ) from your c++ file ( `.cpp` ). In your header file, declare just the prototype of the `click event`:

```
private: System::Void btnLoad_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
```

In your .cpp file, you should have something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace TestImage;

System::Void Form1::btnLoad_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        OpenFileDialog^ ofd = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
        //insert here the filter if you want
        //ofd->Filter..
        if (ofd->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {

             pbImage->Image = Image::FromFile(ofd->FileName);
        }
    }
```

Remember to resize accordingly to your image `pbImage` and you will be fine.

Hope this one helps.